# positioning on image on top of another creates gap

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to have a simple profile page where I have a wide cover image and then I am trying to position the logo image on top of it. And then the rest of the information come.

I tried this one: stackoverflow.com/questions/2941189/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div and I was able to put one image on top of another but the rest of the information was also placed on the images for some reason.

I tried things myself, here is my html:

```
        <div id="container-biz-header">
            <div id="feature-graphic-background" style="background-image: url('../Images/FG-10000001.jpg'); width: 700px; height 200px; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
            </div>
            <div id="logo-background" style="background-image: url('../Images/Logo-10000001.jpg'); width: 150px; height 150px; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
            </div>
        </div>
... here comes a lot of more information
```

My CSS is as follows:

```
#container-biz-header {
    margin: auto;
}

#feature-graphic-background {
    margin: auto;
}

#logo-background {
    width: 160px;
    height: 170px;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 10;
    position:relative;
    top: -100px;
    right: -300px;
}
```

At last I got what I wanted, to put a cover image and then a logo on top of it.
However, now there is a big gap between these images and the rest of the information, because `#container-biz-header` keeps its original height which is `height('#feature-graphic-background')+height('#logo-background')`.

What can I do to avoid this gap? or otherwise, is there a better way to position the logo image on top of the cover image which avoids this gap?

Comment: Please, fiddle. Will be faster for people to answer!

Comment: consider `absolute` positioning http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: I put your code in a fiddle, but still can't figure what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/es_kaija/0jsqpq4L/1/

Comment: Ok, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/es_kaija/0jsqpq4L/3/

Comment: I did not get what you want, but you miss ":" in your styles for height, you have "height 200" and "height 150"  but  "height :200"  "height:150" you must have

Comment: Messy code won't get you answers.

Comment: I should learn to use fiddle. Sorry for that, I'm a server guy. Thank you for your help. I took your advice Kristine and put height on my container, I'll just use that for now. If you'll publish your comment as answer I'll mark it as the right one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Done and done. Fiddle is really easy and really helpful, you don't need to create files to test stuff. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/es_kaija/0jsqpq4L/3/

Watch your spelling :)

```
  #container-biz-header {
  margin: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add *height:200px* CSS to #container-biz-header to stop it from getting height('#feature-graphic-background')+height('#logo-background') height , here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QphhPcg6lW2tsHQ8ToIF?p=preview) .

and in your html, you have a typo too. "height 200px" and  "height 150px" should have ":" .

```
#container-biz-header {
   margin: auto;
   height:200px;
 }
```